# DotNetNuke Manual

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

Is there any free DotNetNuke manual? and also C# version of the program?

Thank in advance

Comment: With a bit of reading on the DNN website you could have uncovered this information

Answer (score 2):

> DotNetNuke User Manuals for all the
>   latest DNN versions. Available for
>   purchase in PDF format from
>   [Snowcovered](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=295&sid=24362) or visit the [Online
>   Help](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Knowledge/DotNetNukeOnlineHelp/tabid/787/Default.aspx) section of this site.

You can purchase the user manual [here](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=15931).

Source: [Documentation section](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Support/Documentation/eBooksandTrainingVideos/tabid/810/Default.aspx) of the official site, which has [Downloadable Files](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Support/Documentation/DownloadableFiles/tabid/478/Default.aspx), [eBooks and Training Videos](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Support/Documentation/eBooksandTrainingVideos/tabid/810/Default.aspx), [DotNetNuke Books](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Support/Documentation/DotNetNukeBooks/tabid/1334/Default.aspx) and [Learning Resources](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Support/Documentation/LearningResources/tabid/535/Default.aspx).

And there's no official release of the program in C#, although some has translated it to C#, but no official thing.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not a C# version at this time, and no converters out there work right. One day maybe someone on the core team will do a real conversation, but they have tried and failed.

Here are the **FREE** manuals in PDF, you may have to register:

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Support/Documentation/DownloadableFiles/tabid/478/Default.aspx

Admin Docs:
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Development/Downloads/DotNetNukeDownloadsLibrary/tabid/1374/Default.aspx

Here are previous versions and thier docs these are also **FREE** (the version selctor is to the right.  Some versions have docs and others don't):

http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/39104

If you look at 4.9 docs they are similar to 5. If you do not find the info you are looking for you will have to do what the previous answer states and buy additional material, but trust me you really shouldn't need it, all the info is out there for **free**.

If you are looking for something specfic, please let me know, as I have been working in DNN for some time.